# JQuery and validate plugin - how to add a promotional message on submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I need to put a promotional message either at the bottom of the form or in an alert when a user meets certain criteria. I think an alert might be best. It's to do with certain postcodes so I will need to write a regex (I haven't done this yet). It needs to happen when the user clicks submit and before it goes to the server. I'm not sure how to write this and where it should be placed in my script. This is what I have so far if it helps.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#orderForm").validate({
    onfocusout: function(element) { 
        this.element(element); 
    },
    rules: {
        shipFirstName: {
            required: true,
        },
        shipFamilyName: {
            required: true,
        },
        shipPhoneNumber: {
            required: true,
        },
        shipStreetName: {
            required: true,
        },
        shipCity: {
            required: true,
        },
        billEmailAddress: {
            required: true,
        },
        billPhoneNumber: {
            required: true,
        },
        billCardNumber: {
            required: true,
        },
        billCardType: {
            required: true,
        },
        shipPostalCode: {
            postalCode: true,
        },
        fidelityCardNumber: {
            creditCardNumber: true,
        },
    }, //end of rules
}); // end of validate
}); // end of function

$.validator.addMethod('postalCode', 
function (value, element) 
{
      return this.optional(element) || /^[A-Z]{2}\d{1,2}\s\d{1,2}[A-Z]{2}$/.test(value);
}, 'Please enter a valid Postal Code');


$.validator.addMethod('creditCardNumber', 
function(value, element) 
{
    return this.optional(element) || /^[A-Z]{1}([A-Z]|\d){4}\s?([A-Z]|\d){5}\s?([A-Z]|\d){3}\d{1}(\!|\&|\@|\?){1}$/.test(value);
}, 'Please enter a valid card number');
```

Comment: On behalf of web users everywhere, please, please don't display your promotion as an alert().

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do something like this (this will replace the default submit behavior):

```
$("#orderForm").validate({
    submitHandler: function(form) {
        // code to display personal message
        // code to handle form submission 
    },
    onfocusout: function(element) { 
    ...
```

Comment: I have the regex that I need to validate the postcodes, this is /[MK]{2}[1-15|17|19|77]{2}/
The message will be something like: You have been entered in a competition to win a special prize.
How do I add this information into the submitHandler?
Sorry, I am very new to all this

Comment: What is the code you need to submit the form? Is it form.submit() ?

Answer (score 0):

Write a click function for submit button and call ajax function in that

```
$("#submit").click(function(){
  alert("This is a promotional message on submit");
  //here write ur ajax code.
});
```

[ajax](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax) in Jquery.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide a submitHandler as an option to the [validate](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#options) method.

Answer (score 0):

```
submitHandler: function(form) {
    if ($("form #hasAsked").val() != 'true' && /[MK]{2}[1-15|17|19|77]{2}/.test($("#shipPostalCode").val()) {
        openModalDialog();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
},
...
```

An a function

```
function openModalDialog() { 
     $("<div>Wanna buy?? <button value="yes" id="y/><button value="no" id="n/></div>")
          .after("body p:first-child")
          .show('slide')
          .find("#y, #n").click(function() { $("form #hasAsked").val("true") /* default: false */; })
          .end()
          .find("#y")
          .click(function() { $("form #hiddenbuy").val("true"); })
          .end()
          .find("#n")
          .click(function() { $("form #hiddenbuy").val("false"); })
}
```